# How to programmatically insert a parent element in all existing CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, phpstorm

I have a large CSS file with over 1000 selectors. I want to add the ID `MyId` as parent element to ALL of the selectors.

For example:

```
p{
...
}
.myclass li{
...
}
```

will become:

```
#MyId p{
...
}
#MyId .myclass li{
...
}
```

Is there any way to do this automatically, for example in PhpStorm or a tool?

Comment: You could do it with javascript or jQuery if you can't alter the html code. Other option would be to use body or html selector to target all child selectors as body p {}, body .myclass li {}.

Comment: If you were using SASS, you could simply wrap your entire stylesheet in the desired ID selector and it would render the child selectors as desired.

Comment: Try https://github.com/vic/prefix-css

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace with the regex option.

find: `^(.*)\{$`

replacement: `#MyId $1{`

This will match all starting CSS lines *e.g. `[selector] {`* and prefix it with `#MyId`.

[image: Regex Replacement]

I suggest looking into using SASS for more control over compiling css files.

> **Note:** this will not fix compound selectors such as `html, body {`, which will only prefix the compound value as `#MyID html, body {`

Comment: This will also affect media queries (`#MyID @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`) and will not work for multiline selectors.